# Traditional Text of the Gemoro Yerushalmi Maseches Peah online

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-yerushalmi, masechet-peah

Where on line can I find the text of the Gemoro Yerushalmi Maseches Peah, laid out according to the traditional dappim. Sefaria is excellent but lacks the traditional layout. I am following an online Daf Yomi shiur and want to plot the progress through the dappim.

There should be 37 dappim in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want [this edition](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14139&st=&pgnum=184) available on HebrewBooks.org.